# org.apache.maven.reactor.MavenExecutionException: Failed to validate POM for project

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom

Estou com um pequeno problema no meu pom dando a seguinte mensagem:

Validation Messages:

```
[0]  'dependencies.dependency.version' is missing for com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:pom
```

Reason: Failed to validate POM for project com.projeto.api:api at /root/meu-projeto/pom.xml

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.reactor.MavenExecutionException: Failed to validate POM for project com.projeto.api:api at /root/meu-projeto/pom.xml
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:404)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.InvalidProjectModelException: Failed to validate POM for project com.projeto.api:api at /root/meu-projeto/pom.xml
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.processProjectLogic(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1077)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:880)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromSourceFileInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:508)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.build(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProject(DefaultMaven.java:604)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:487)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:391)

segue o meu pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.2.7.RELEASE
         
    
    com.projeto
    api
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    api
    Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--             security                 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--             end security            -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson/jackson-bom -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.moip</groupId>
        <artifactId>sdk-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.slugify</groupId>
        <artifactId>slugify</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

insira o código aqui

Answer (score 1):

Falta você definir a versão da dependência **com.fasterxml.jackson**

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```